# what is the difference between /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd

Tags: passwd, shadow

What is the major difference between `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd`

In `/etc/shadow` we have the same data as in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I can't comment but you can find informations there : https://askubuntu.com/questions/445361/what-is-difference-between-etc-shadow-and-etc-passwd

Comment: This question is predicated upon two false premises.  First: _We_ don't necessarily have `/etc/shadow` in the first place, although some of us might have an `/etc/spwd.db`.  Second: They do _not_ have the same data.

Comment: There is _no_ request for learning materials in this question, as _three_ people have so far flagged it.  That is an abuse of that closure reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Historically `/etc/passwd` had all of the user data, there was no shadow.
However it was discovered that a dictionary attack could be done on the file, to discover passwords (if they are in the dictionary).

Therefore it was decided to remove the passwords from `/etc/passwd`, the rest of the file remained, as it was used my many programs e.g. `ls`. The passwords were moved to `/etc/shadow`, and this file was made so that only `root` can read it.

`/etc/passwd` now has an `x` for the password field.
`/etc/shadow` only shares the first field (the key-field / the user name).
`/etc/shadow` has been expanded to contain other password management fields.

Answer (score 3):

The existence of the two files is a consequence of that `/etc/passwd` is a text file that can be read by other applications (as `finger`, `ident` or  `ls` for example), so an attacker could gain access to the information of the file that included the hashed password.

To increase security, the hashed password that used to be in the file was moved to other file called `/etc/shadow` that is accessible only by **root**

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that they contain different pieces of data.

`passwd` contains the users' public information (UID, full name, home directory), while `shadow` contains the hashed password and the password expiry data. The reasons for the division are partly historical.

See the man pages: [`passwd(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) and [`shadow(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html)